# How to define the color of any side of the "stroke" of "Rect", as in the following illustration （fabricjs - Rect -stroke）

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to try to define a different color for any edge "stroke" in "Rect", but I can't do it through stroke.

What is the way to implement the following illustration?

[image: Rect with stroke color on one side]

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, which is achieved by drawing two graphics rectangles and line segments, but this solution is not perfect, for example, when the rectangle is rotated, the red line segment will shake, which is a troublesome problem, I don't know Is there any other solution, if so please let me know

```
    const Rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top: 100,
        left:100,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    const coords = Rect._getCoords(true);
    const Line = new fabric.Line(Line.tl.x, Line.tl.y,Line.br.x, Line.br.y, {fill: 'blue'});
    baseCanvas.add(Line)
    Rect.Line = Line,
    baseCanvas.add(Rect)
    baseCanvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a short description of how your solution works, instead of just posting the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).